# ASP MVC + Castle + nHibernate how to connect?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, castle-windsor, castle

What is the best way to connect asp mvc + castle windsor + nhibernate?

I have repository which is injected into my controller constructor.

Is this a good and correct way of doing this :

```
Component.For<ISessionFactory>().UsingFactoryMethod(()=> CreateSessionFactory() ).LifeStyle.Singleton,

Component.For<ISession>().UsingFactoryMethod ( k=>k.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
```

and then just inject `ISession` into repository constructor ?

What about transactions and disposing session ?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

MVC + Castle + NHibernate? The best way would be to use S#arp Architecture instead of reinventing the wheel.

> Pronounced "Sharp Architecture," this
>   is a solid architectural foundation
>   for rapidly building maintainable web
>   applications leveraging the ASP.NET
>   MVC framework with NHibernate. The
>   primary advantage to be sought in
>   using any architectural framework is
>   to decrease the code one has to write
>   while increasing the quality of the
>   end product. A framework should enable
>   developers to spend little time on
>   infrastructure details while allowing
>   them to focus their attentions on the
>   domain and user experience.
>   Accordingly, S#arp Architecture
>   adheres to the following key
>   principles:
>
> - Focused on Domain Driven Design
> - Loosely coupled
> - Preconfigured Infrastructure
> - Open Ended Presentation
>
> The overall goal of this is to allow
>   developers to worry less about
>   application "plumbing" and to spend
>   most of their time on adding value for
>   the client by focusing on the business
>   logic and developing a rich user
>   experience.

A full example can be found [here](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Northwind).

Comment: Castle has support for it, there's no reinventing the wheel going on.

Answer (score 0):

I created a facility for you and anyone else who wants to do this.

https://github.com/haf/Castle.Facilities.NHibernate/wiki/NHibernate-Facility---Quick-Start

**Nuget: `Castle.Facilities.NHibernate`**

Tell me if you find it worthwhile. It's very minimalistic. Just put a [Transaction] around the command handler that is handling the current unit of work. I don't recommend multiple services with disparate transactions. As such, I created a new lifestyle in Windsor called *per transaction*.

I can give you more help on the castle mailing list.